# I have a nextjs project inside pages I created a file called [collectionId].jsx and tailwind does not work

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a next.js project, inside pages I created a file called [collectionId].jsx but tailwind css does not work? When I change the name to [collectionId].js removing the x it works?  My question is why does tailwind css not work, if it work in other files I have ending with .jsx could be because of the brackets? I'd appreciate any insight to this. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `tailwind.config.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Your config is likely looking for a glob path of pure text with a file with extension `.jsx` and isn't interpreting the `]` as part of the text name.

If you need the brackets you probably need to update how it globs files to include the brackets.

This is a bit hard to solve without seeing the webpack or tailwind config though.